# Django-allauth Facebook error

Tags: django, facebook-graph-api, django-allauth

I am going to implement login with facebook and google using django-allauth app,but i am getting one error i.e
`You are not logged in: You are not logged in. Please log in and try again.`

```
My Facebook App Settings
```

[image: Setting Image 1]

[image: Setting Image 2]

What should i do now??

Comment: Can you add more details, e.g. **when** you get the error (i.e. how far you get in the login process - what happens when you go to `/auth/facebook/login/`) and what your configuration is (e.g. include screenshots from `/admin/socialaccount/socialapp/` with blanked out credentials).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solved my problem:

```
Valid Oauth redirect URI ---> set to http://localhost:8000/
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your redirect URI to

```
http://localhost:8000/accounts/facebook/login/callback/
```

and also make sure to have SITE_ID = 1 in settings.